# MQQueueManager(String queueManagerName) throws MQException

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a java program to browse a message from queue.

When i run the application it shows the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" error 
   Also i have jar com.ibm.mq which contains class MQQueueManager. but i am getting error message like "This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

2nd question
  It is a program to browse message. after browsing the message how to get only the messageID from the message.

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the error you are seeing is caused when people grab the jar files rather than installing the client from the vendor distribution media.  If you did not install the IBM MQ client from the media, you can download it for free as [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75).  This will provide the complete client, the Initial Verification Program (IVP) that tests the installation, as well as a number of other diagnostics.

As for the message ID...

```
     MQMessage myMessage = new MQMessage();
     byte myMessageID = myMessage.messageId;
```

...as per the docs [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMessage.html) and [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMD.html#messageId).